# Event is tracked multiple times in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS code where I am tracking a purchase of customer. If someone clicks on final submit button in cart, event "purchase" is tracked. Then, customer continue to Trustpay. If customer goes back to the cart, and click submit again, this event is called again.

1. I want only one purchase event per purchase.
2. I want to be sure that customer wont have event without buying something.

Also, I have a limited access to website code. I have access only via Tag manager and control tracking from scripts...

first:

```
function billingInformationListener() {
  if (dataLayer[0].ecommerce.checkout.actionField.step === 2) {
    let accept = $('#place_order');
    $(accept).unbind();
    if (accept) {
      $(accept).one("click", function () {
      //$(accept).click(function () {
        if (document.querySelector('#terms').checked) {
          trackBillingInf();
          trackPurchase();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

in trackpurchase() there are only attributes from dataLayer, so all data about current purchase.

Comment: Side note; `if (accept) {` will always be truthy.  jQuery objects, and objects in general, are truthy by nature.

Comment: If you have no access to the backend, you can't check to see if the transaction has already been submitted. I think the only way you can do this within the page, is set a cookie with the transaction ID or something to say it's already been submitted. Then only call the `trackPurchase()` if the cookie doesn't exist.

Comment: i understand what you mean, but i am sure i dont know how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you want to make it without backend, you need
When a user clicks on submit you should take response, if a response is a success you should write some variable `wasSubmitted = true`, and before call `trackBillingInf` you must check `if(!wasSubmitted)`
Better save a variable in Local Storage, because the user can submit form from another tab